# I am getting a warning comparing my OPTIONAL value to not-nil will always return true

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have declared a type called "JournalEntry" as an optional and have it set to nil. Then when the VC loads I test to make sure that the object has been injected before trying to use it, but I get an error that says "Comparing non-optional value of type 'JournalEntry' to nil always returns true".

But I have it set as an optional and to nil...

Here's the code:

```
class AddJournalEntryVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var willEdit:Bool?
    var entryForEdit:JournalEntry? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if isEditing {
            guard let entry = entryForEdit, entry != nil else{ //Comparing non-optional value of type 'JournalEntry' to nil always returns true
                return
            }
            dateLabel.text = entry.dateString!
            timeLabel.text = entry.timeString!
            timestamp = entry.timestamp!
        }
    }
```

Where has my thinking gone wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You just unwrapped the optional. The value cannot be nil. It's not an optional anymore. Remove `, entry != nil` and you'll be ok.

Comment: So simply doing 'guard let entry = entryForEdit else {}' will ensure that entry is not nil?

Comment: 'guard let entry = entryForEdit else {}' is asking "Hey Swift, please check out entryForEdit, and if you get something non-nil back, create a constant called entry. Otherwise, do the stuff in the else statement.

Comment: @CodyLucas Yes, absolutely. Unwrapping with `guard let entry = entryForEdit else` will guarantee that `entry` is not nil when used after the `guard`.

Comment: Just like `if let` unwraps an optional into its inner scope, `guard let` unwraps it to the enclosing scope. So if the guard check passes, then entry is unwrapped, no longer an optional, and is guaranteed to not be nil. If it were nil, you’d enter the guard’s else clause.

Comment: @Moritz Awesome, thank you. If you want to answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `entry != nil` clause and it will work as you require. The `if let` statement that proceeds it performs the not-nil check already.

```
guard let entry = entryForEdit else {
    return
}
```